# How to Loop in loop Python - work with columns

Tags: python

```
  radky_A = ['A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6']
  radky_B = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6']
  for j in radky_A:
      sentence = sheet.get(j).first()
      exa = sentence.split()
      words = (" ".join(exa[-2:]))
      sheet.update('B2', [[words]])
```

I need change sheet.update B2-B6 in loop radky_A.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the index of the item using `range()` instead, which can be used as the index for both lists.

In this example, I'm using the index to get the sentence at `radky_A[j]` and update `radky_B[j]`.

```
radky_A = ['A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6']
radky_B = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6']
for j in range(len(radky_A)):
    sentence = sheet.get(radky_A[j]).first()
    exa = sentence.split()
    words = (" ".join(exa[-2:]))
    sheet.update(radky_B[j], [[words]])
```